# -CMatch two variables

Tags: regex, variables, powershell

Regular Expressions.  Fun stuff.  Essentially I want to take two variables and do a -match (or in this case a -cmatch) to look at the entire variable and match it with the other.  The variables could include captial letters, numbers, special characters. I just need to ensurey the are identical.

Example below of what I am looking for:

```
$var1 = "Hello32@^78"
$var2 = "Hello32@^78"

$Check = $var1 -cmatch $var2
```

Above, $Check comes back "False".  It doesn't seem to like the characters.

Once working, I would do something based on that $Check

```
If($check-eq$true) {do something}
ElseIf($check-eq$False)  {do something else}
```

I know I am missing something completly that I have overlooked somewhere.  I'm just racking my brain on it at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the special characters in the expression you're comparing against. i.e.:

```
PS> $var1 -cmatch [regex]::escape($var2)
True
```

Though, you say you need to ensure they are **identical**. If that's the case, `-match` is the wrong operator and you should use:

```
PS> $var1 -ceq $var2
True
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  Works great and appreciate it!